# String.Contains doesn't work on web exception because it has a small dots between the words

Tags: string, vb.net, contains

I am checking if a web exception message contains a string I have.
My string is: "The remote name could not be resolved"

The web exception message is:"***The remote name could not be resolved:***"
You would expect it to work, but if you copy-paste and enlarge the web exception here you will notice ***tiny dots*** between every word.
Those dots apparently ruins the contains function I use.

```
    If exWeb.Message.Contains("The remote name could not be resolved") Then
        'Do something...
    End If
```

How can I compare those strings without the dots or ignore the dots or any other solution?

Comment: Why are you analyzing the message text instead of the exception type?

Comment: As for the tiny dots, do you happen to have ticked "Display whitespace characters"?

Comment: "draw_white_space": "selection",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on the message string isn't very future proof, as the framework developers may decide to change the message in the future for various reasons (to make it more explanatory, change grammar .etc.) or your code could be running in a different locale with a different language causing the error message to be different.

I suggest you check the `Status` property instead.

See the documentation of the Enum. I think you're looking for a `WebException` with a `Status` of `NameResolutionFailure`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus(v=vs.110).aspx